# How to flatten SQLAlchemy results when querying via association table

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a `SampleMessage` table where each message can be tagged with multiple tags from the `SampleTag` table. To accomplish this I use an association table called `SampleMessageTag`.

I'm trying to create a query that returns the data in a cleaner way. Currently any given result looks like this:

```
{
    ...SampleMessageData
    tags: [{
        // this is from the SampleMessageTag table
        sample_message_id: 1,
        tag_id: 2,
        id: 3,
        tag: {
            // this is from the Tag table
            name: 'Blabla',
            tag_type: 'industry',
            id: 2,
        }
    }]
}
```

But I want to flatten this result so that the tag is just a single dict -- instead of a dict nested within another dict.

Ideally I want it to look like:

```
{
    ...SampleMessageData
    tags: [{
        // only data from from the Tag table
            name: 'Blabla',
            tag_type: 'industry',
            id: 2,
        }
    }]
}
```

Is this possible to do via the SqlAlchemy query or do I have to loop through all the results after I get them back?

Here's what my query looks like currently:

```
def get_samples(self, skip, limit, industries, annotated_only, months, origins) -> models.SampleMessage:
        results_query = self.db.query(models.SampleMessage
            ).join(
                models.SampleMessageTag
            ).options(
                contains_eager(models.SampleMessage.tags
                ).joinedload(
                    models.SampleMessageTag.tag
                )
            ).filter(
                models.SampleMessage.active==True,
            )

        if annotated_only:
            results_query = results_query.filter(
                models.SampleMessage.annotated==True
            )

        if industries:
            results_query = results_query.filter(models.SampleMessageTag.tag_id.in_(industries))

        if origins:
            results_query = results_query.filter(models.SampleMessage.origin.in_(origins))

        if months:
            results_query = results_query.filter(extract('month', models.SampleMessage.first_sent).in_(months))

        total_rows = results_query.count()

        results = results_query.limit(
                limit
            ).offset(
                limit*skip  # skip in this case refers to page
            ).all()

        return {
            "count": total_rows,
            "items": results
        }
```

Comment: Looking at [Many to Many](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/basic_relationships.html#many-to-many) documentation, instead of having 2 one-many relationships, you should configure many-to-many using `seconday=...` argument. In this case you query will be simplier and the result should be exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: It looks like he is using an Association Object instead of an Assocation Table. In that case using `secondary` is discouraged as noted [here](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/basic_relationships.html#association-object)! Isn't he looking for the [`association_proxy`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/extensions/associationproxy.html#module-sqlalchemy.ext.associationproxy)?

Comment: The sample data shown suggests there are no additional data in the association table, hence I concluded the association object is not necessary. But it is all up to @sup_er_dub.

Comment: Yes, you're right that's it's not necessary. But the current data show that he has `id` as additional data in `SampleMessageTags`!